# I have a card database that has the columns (String cardnumber, String pin, double balance) and I am having issues making a deposit to card

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, gradle

> Here is my method for the deposit method, I have tried making a deposit but the balance is stays at 0.0 which is the initial value. I am a little confused I am able to print the balance fine in another method but when it comes to updating I am having no luck. I would appreciate some help for my method.

```
public void deposit(String number, String pin, double amount) {
    String sql = "UPDATE cards " +
            "SET balance = ?" +
            "WHERE number = ? AND pin = ?";

    try(Connection c = this.connect();
        PreparedStatement statement = c.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        statement.setString(1, number);
        statement.setString(2, pin);
        statement.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while(rs.next()) {
            double x = rs.getDouble(3);
            double t = x + amount;
            statement.setDouble(3, t);
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 parameters that you must pass:

```
statement.setDouble(1, amount);
statement.setString(2, number);
statement.setString(3, pin);
statement.executeUpdate();
```

Also, you should have a space after `"SET balance = ?"`:

```
String sql = "UPDATE cards " +
        "SET balance = ? " +
        "WHERE number = ? AND pin = ?";
```

But since you are doing a deposit, maybe you want to add the amount to the current balance, so change the query to this:

```
String sql = "UPDATE cards " +
        "SET balance = balance + ? " +
        "WHERE number = ? AND pin = ?";
```

Also, this:

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

while(rs.next()) {
    double x = rs.getDouble(3);
    double t = x + amount;
    statement.setDouble(3, t);
}
```

is pointless.
The string `sql` contains an `UPDATE` statement which does not return a `ResultSet`.

Comment: I have done everything above and still the balance is not updating correctly :(

Comment: Did you add the space after `SET balance = ?`? Remove the try/catch block to see if there is an error. If not then maybe there is no row with that number and pin. Or its balance is null.

Comment: balance is set by default to 0 I can see in the table I have added the space after the SET "balance + balance = ? "

Comment: It is not `SET "balance + balance = ? "` but `"SET balance = balance + ? "`.

Comment: String sql = "UPDATE cards " +
                "SET balance = balance + ? " +
                "WHERE number = ? AND pin = ?";

Comment: this is what I have

Comment: Yes, this is correct. If you don't get any errors and the parameters that you pass exist in the table then it should do the update. Remove `ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);` and the `while` loop.

Comment: I have a containsRecord boolean which passes so I know it is finding the card. I just dont understand why the balance is not being added everything looks fine I have been done as told